# HMVC AJAX PAGINATION passing data to a view that is moduled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

i am currently working on this ajax view and i saw this link on google.

http://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/

the links are not working. i think it is because of this line

```
    //load the view
    $this->load->view('posts/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
```

which i cannot do because i am using hmvc templating.

here is  the codes

```
$data['content_view'] = 'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);
```

that lead me to the

```
    <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>
```

how am i going to pass the  `$data, false` to my `$this->load->view($content_view)`?

Comment: Have you leave the comment/question on link you provided? It would be fastest way to get an answer - to ask custom code author himself.

Comment: i have. but i thought of also asking it here so that it would be faster. whoever answers first. :)

Comment: Good point. :) I can see they propose `strtolower('file_name.php')`. If you use CI v3 that would be wrong, because CI 3 demands classes to be `ucfirst('class_name.php')`.

Comment: i dont fully get it. can you give me further explanation? maybe we can chat ? thanks. :)

Comment: Controllers, libraries and methods files should be named with first capital. Eg. `Post.php NOT post.php`. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming).

Comment: yes. i have done it. i have costomized it. but as you see, i also need to pass the $data variable to `$this->load->view($content_view);` i tried to do   `$data['content_view'] = "'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read',$data";
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);` but php read it as `'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read',$data.php`